# MS Access VBA Order of Operations

Tags: vba, ms-access, operator-precedence

Here are the lines of code that are providing incorrect values:
(well, one of them is correct and one is wrong)

value1 = (partslist * 0.8) + laborlist

value2 = (partslist + laborlist) * 0.8

(FYI in this case the value of partslist was $870.80 and laborlist was $25.00 but both formulas produce a result of $716.64 even though that is not correct)

I do not understand why Access VBA seems to be ignoring the order of operations?

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The calculations are different. Operator precedence does not apply here. The portions of the calculation in parentheses is always done first - this is basic math.

The first formula discounts `partlist` by 20% and then adds `laborlist`

```
870.80 * 0.8 = 696.64 + 25 = 721.64
```

The second one adds `partlist` and `laborlist` and then applies the 20% discount to the total.

```
870.80 + 25.00 = 895.80 * 0.8 = 716.64
```

Which one is correct and which is not depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to discount just the parts, the first one is correct; if you want to discount the entire invoice, the second one is correct.

You can verify this yourself using the Windows Calculator. It accepts `()`, so you can type the exact expression (including the parentheses) to perform the two calculations.